# multiple values for argument pass through

Tags: python, oop, variables, super

I don't understand the error linked in this post. why do I have to pass the variable level straight as a string into `super().__init__` instead of a variable with a default string value for it to work? how would it work if I had multiple of these variables to pass through `super().__init__` how would it work? Here is the code below and the error is an image.
Thank you!

```
class School:
  def __init__(self, name, level, numofs):
    self.name = name
    self.level = level
    self.numofs = numofs
  
  def get_name(self):
    return self.name
  def get_level(self):
    return self.level
  def get_numbofs(self):
    return self.numofs
  
  def set_numofs(self, num):
    self.numofs = num
  
  def __repr__(self):
    return "A {} school named {} with {} students".format(self.level , self.name, str(self.numofs))

hamilton = School("hamilton", "high", 16)
print(hamilton.get_name())
print(hamilton)

class PrimarySchool(School):
  def __init__(self, name, numofs, ptime):
    super().__init__(self, name, numofs, level = "primary")
    self.ptime = ptime
  def get_time(self):
    return self.ptime

  def __repr__(self):
    old = super().__repr__()
    return old + "the pickup policy is {}".format(ptime)

turtle = PrimarySchool("turtle", 16, "late pick-up")
```

here is the error linked as a pic(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGj94.png)

Comment: The problem is that `numofs` is assigned to the `level` parameter, as it is the next positional parameter defined by `School.__init__`. If you want to mix up the order, you need to pass *everything* as keyword arguments (as recommended by https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: The signature of `School` specifies `name`, `level`, and then `numofs` in that order. If you wish to specify `level=smth` you will need to either place level at the end of the signature or also specify `numofs=smth`. What's happening is you are passing level twice through the super call and not passing numofs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant code from your post:

```
class School:
  def __init__(self, name, level, numofs):
```

```
class PrimarySchool(School):
  def __init__(self, name, numofs, ptime):
    super().__init__(self, name, numofs, level = "primary")
```

In `PrimarySchool.__init__`, you are passing the `level` argument for `School.__init__` both as a positional argument (`numofs`) and a keyword argument (`level = "primary"`), which is ambiguous. To resolve this, you should only use one of them. For example,

1. Using positional arguments

```
class PrimarySchool(School):
  def __init__(self, name, numofs, ptime):
    super().__init__(name, "primary", numofs)
```

2. Using keyword arguments

```
class PrimarySchool(School):
  def __init__(self, name, numofs, ptime):
    super().__init__(name=name, level="primary", numofs=numofs)
```

Comment: so i can't use keyword and positional arguments in this same line?

Comment: @Hani You can, but you can't assign two values to *the same* argument in one function call. For example, `super().__init__(name=name, level="primary", level="secondary", numofs=numofs)` would also be an error.